# using apple script to exit app at a specified cpu%

Tags: automation, applescript, cpu-usage

I want a script that will exit an application after it has finished processing files. the code below is one that I have tried creating myself by researching others creations but have had no luck in actually getting it to work. this specific software dose not support automated workflows therefore the only trigger I could find was to go by the cpu% as it can use upto 100% when in use or as little as 1.3% when idle,

```
getProcessPercentCPU("Mixed In Key 8")
set someProcess to getProcessPercentCPU("Mixed In Key 8")
on getProcessPercentCPU(someProcess)

repeat

    do shell script "/bin/ps -xco %cpu,command | /usr/bin/awk '/" & someProcess & "$/ {print $1}'"

    if someProcess is less than "2.0" then
        application "Mixed In Key 8" quit
    end if
end repeat
end getProcessPercentCPU
```

if anyone can help me with getting this to work or have any recommendations that would be very much appreciated. also I am new to applescripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ve got it basically correct, but it looks like you tried to jump ahead before verifying that the pieces work correctly. It may also help if you name the handlers and variables what they are trying to do. For example, in this case, it seems like your handler is monitoring an app, and then quitting that app once it hits a low CPU usage.

Note that I’ve changed the process name to `TaskPaper` in the examples, because I have that available.

```
quitOnLowCPU("TaskPaper")

on quitOnLowCPU(processToMonitor)
    set processCPU to do shell script "/bin/ps -xco %cpu,command | /usr/bin/awk '/" & processToMonitor & "$/ {print $1}'"
    display dialog processCPU
end quitOnLowCPU
```

At this point, we know two things: that the shell script is returning the number we want, and that it’s returning it as a string.

To reliably compare numbers, we need to convert them to numeric values.

```
quitOnLowCPU("TaskPaper")

on quitOnLowCPU(processToMonitor)
    set processCPU to do shell script "/bin/ps -xco %cpu,command | /usr/bin/awk '/" & processToMonitor & "$/ {print $1}'"

    --convert the shell script response string to a number
    set processCPU to processCPU as number
    --compare to the threshold of quitting
    if processCPU is less than 2.0 then
        tell application processToMonitor to quit
    end if
end quitOnLowCPU
```

This works, but it also tries to quit `processToMonitor` even if `processToMonitor` isn’t running.

```
quitOnLowCPU("TaskPaper")

on quitOnLowCPU(processToMonitor)
    set processCPU to do shell script "/bin/ps -xco %cpu,command | /usr/bin/awk '/" & processToMonitor & "$/ {print $1}'"

    if processCPU is "" then
        --the process is gone. We're done
        return
    end if

    --convert the shell script response string to a number
    set processCPU to processCPU as number
    --compare to the threshold of quitting
    if processCPU is less than 2.0 then
        tell application processToMonitor to quit
    end if
end quitOnLowCPU
```

Now we’re ready to add a `repeat` around the handler:

```
quitOnLowCPU("TaskPaper")

on quitOnLowCPU(processToMonitor)
    repeat
        set processCPU to do shell script "/bin/ps -xco %cpu,command | /usr/bin/awk '/" & processToMonitor & "$/ {print $1}'"
        if processCPU is "" then
            --the process is gone. We're done
            return
        end if

        --convert the shell script response string to a number
        set processCPU to processCPU as number
        --compare to the threshold of quitting
        if processCPU is less than 2.0 then
            tell application processToMonitor to quit
        end if
        delay 1
    end repeat
end quitOnLowCPU
```

I added a `delay` on each repeat because endlessly repeating scripts can often become a CPU hog in themselves.